# How do I implement Socket.IO in an electron app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, electron

I want to implement Socket.IO in an Electron app, however I have found **no** documentation and **no** examples of how this could work.
If someone could explain to me how two or more clients could communicate via the electron app, I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You know, the electron app will be running at end user.
So you should create Socket server at somewhere sth like Cloud server and your electron app should contain one socket.io client instance.

At Socket server

```
const app = require('express')();

const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', () => { /* … */ });
server.listen(3000);
```

And at frontend (your case Electron app side)

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io('http://localhost');
  socket.on('connect', function(){});
  socket.on('event', function(data){});
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){});
</script>
```

or

```
// with ES6 import
import io from 'socket.io-client';
 
const socket = io('http://localhost');
```

So that users can communicate inside your Electron app.